# Count of Excel based on 2 column criteria and counting the 3rd column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a count of how many date items fall within Data 1 & Data 2

ie:

1. x-1 will have a count of 2
2. x-2 will have a count of 1
3. -x-3 will have a count of 2
4. -y-1 will have a count of 2

What would be the best way to go abouts when approaching this?

| Data 1 | Data 2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | Date 1 |
| x | 1 | Date 1 |
| x | 1 | Date 2 |
| x | 2 | Date 3 |
| x | 2 | Date 3 |
| y | 1 | Date 1 |
| y | 1 | Date 1 |

Comment: Your first sentence says that data 2 column is important but your expected results only seem to distinguish categories based on data 1 and date, and has nothing to do with the data 2 value.  Also, anything wrong with using a pivot table for this?

Comment: It's unclear to me if you're referencing the column `Data2` or the last digit of column `Date` in the last digit of your search examples. Could you specify what's referenced?

Comment: and `x-3 will have a count of 0` right?

Comment: This is very ambiguous as you do not mention that Data 1 & 2 are dates (and the values/examples you use 'x, y,  1, 2' leave much of this question open to interpretation and unnecessary problem/riddle solving.  Would recommend you used an example with actual dates instead of 'x, xy' and 'date 1', 'date 2' (a screenshot like the one in my proposed soln then provides an immediate 'visual' aid for those attempting to assist)

Comment: (i.e. you'll need to 'trust' that the answers generated can be generalised' to your specific setup/values etc. - which would generally be the case unless the question requires an exceptionally bespoke method/soln...  Notwithstanding, adapting the solution to meet needs makes one stronger at building/solving problems such as this)

Answer (score 0):

I see only one way to interpret with the available information:

To count the number of times *Date_to_test* falls within *Date_1* and *Date_2* (screenshot below, sheet [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j961-kVloF-Wi3LkvZ?e=h5mXm8)), you could use either the sum or something like a  countifs (with interim calc):

**sum approach**

```
=SUM(1*($C$2:$C$11<=$B$2:$B$11)*($A$2:$A$11<=$C$2:$C$11))
```

**countifs + interim calc**

*helper*

```
=1*(C2<=B2)*(A2<=C2)
```

(additional column, drag down)

*countifs*

```
=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$11,1)
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot for reference]

**Alternative**

- as for the 'sum' approach, sumproduct variants (e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(1*($C$2:$C$11<=$B$2:$B$11),1*($B$2:$B$11>=$A$2:$A$11))`) are calculation/memory intensive
- despite the countifs + helper approach containing more 'visible' data - these values need only be calculated once, the countifs can then be determined independently (assuming no updates to the helper column) - thus making it more memory/calculation efficient depending upon your calculation mode, screen-updating preferences

**Caveat**

- if, by some misfortune re: interpreting your question, you are referring to some other means of establishing whether "date items fall within Data 1 & Data 2", then without knowing what this is, there very low likelihood of being able to guess this correctly